# How to build/run prepared statements in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I don't wish to use ActiveRecord and models. is there a way to build and execute prepared statements easily in Ruby?

I've looked all over the web, and can't seem to find an easy way to do so. I know ActiveRecord builds them in the back-end when you do inserts, but I want to generate them myself if possible.

Comment: There is a way to build and execute statements in ActiveRecord. Are you trying to get away from ActiveRecord completely?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at these:

https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel

or

https://github.com/rails/arel